# Extract specific properties from variable keys

Tags: typescript

Is there a way to rewrite TypeScript like this?

## Before

```
(({id, name}) => ({id, name}))(user)
```

## After

```
const keys = {id, name}
((keys) => (keys))(user)
```

Answer (score 0):

This string `(({id, name}) => ({id, name}))(user)` is a arrow function which accepts object and destructs it in argument list and returns the same object. After definition, this function is immediately called with object `user`.

The typescript is about typing, so if you've declared `user` something like this

```
let user = { id: 1, name: '2' };
```

arrow function will know, that object, passed as argument will have typing like this

```
{ id: number, name: string }
```

and will work.

You can rewrite your arrow function like you want

```
((keys) => (keys))(user)
```

and it will work the same. `keys` will be object of type `{ id: number, name: string }`.

It may be good idea to type your arrow function, so you;ll be able to reuse it. For example

```
((keys: { id: number, name: string }) => (keys))(user)
```

so `keys` will have specific type and it will be checked with type of `user` argument.

You may also pre-define type of `keys` in advance like this

```
type Keys = { id: number, name: string }
```

And use it to type your function

```
((keys: Keys) => (keys))(user)
```

This is similar to what you want to achieve, but in place of `const keys` we use `type Keys` to define type

Comment: Thanks for your answer and sorry I'm late to reply. I'm afraid your code does not work for me. Please let me know if I'm doing it wrong.

```
interface A {
    a: number;
    b: number;
}

type B = Pick<A, "a">;

const a = { a: 1, b: 2 } as A;
console.log(a); // {a: 1, b: 2}

const b = ((keys: B) => (keys))(a)
console.log(b); // {a: 1, b: 2} <= I don't need b

type C = { a: number }
const c = ((keys: C) => (keys))(a)
console.log(c); // {a: 1, b: 2} <= I don't need b
```